# Getting strange result including $i$ while calculating extended period of mortgage.

Tags: matlab, finance

I'm trying to solve a problem about how long a mortgage needs to be extended if the monthly payments are to remain the same and interest rate increases, the code is shown below. However I notice that when the difference between my annual $r$ and $r_1$ is larger than about $0.02$, I keep getting a strange number including $i$. For example when my $r=0.05$ and $r_1=0.08$, I got [image]. I don't know what this result means.

But when my $r=0.05$ and $r_1=0.07$, it works fine and I can get the result of $756$ months. Why would that happen? Then what should my answer be when I have $r$ increasing from $0.05$ to $0.08$?

```
clear;
P = 1000000;
r = 0.05/12;
n = 12*30;
A = ((r*(1+r)^n)*P)/((1+r)^n-1);
r1 = 0.08/12;
n1 = 12*25;
P1 = (A/r)*(1-1/(1+r)^n1);
A1 = ((r1*(1+r1)^n1)*P1)/((1+r1)^n1-1);
syms n
vpa(solve(A==((r1*(1+r1)^n)*P1)/((1+r1)^n-1),n))-n1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've encountered complex numbers.  I suspect what it means is that the equation you're trying to solve has no real solution, so your solver is giving you a complex solution.

If the monthly payment is not enough to cover the interest on the principal, you won't be able to extend the mortgage amortization.

Answer (score 1):

*Just a few comments.*

If I am not mistaken, your calculations seem to be unaccurate. You are looking for the zero of function

$$F(r_1,n)=P_1\frac{r_1 (1+r_1)^n}{(1+r_1)^n-1}-(A+n_1)$$
which has an explicit solution.

Let $Z=(1+r_1)^n$
$$\frac Z{Z-1}=\frac{A+n_1 } {P_1\,r_1 }=k\implies Z=\frac k{k-1}\implies n=\frac{\log \left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)}{\log (1+r_1)}$$ that is to say
$$\color{blue}{n=\frac{1 }{\log (1+r_1)}~\log \left(\frac{A+n_1}{A+n_1-P_1\, r_1}\right)}$$ which shows the problem when $A+n_1\leq P_1\, r_1$

I give you below the numbers I obtained for various values of $r_1$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
r_1 & n \\
 0.0700 &  498.781\\
 0.0705 &  517.623\\
 0.0710 &  539.558\\
 0.0715 &  565.708\\
 0.0720 &  597.941\\
 0.0725 &  639.699\\
 0.0730 &  698.493\\
 0.0735 &  796.738\\
 0.0740 &  1130.18\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $r_1>0.07407$, there is no more real solution.

Notice that
$$F(0.07,756)=-244.767 \qquad \text{while} \qquad F(0.07,499)=-0.420$$